# Glassfish Server Adapter in Eclipse (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:1118080)

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

i deploy my webApp to a glassfish 3.1.2 Server. I use Eclipse Juno SR1 with glassfish Server adapter.
But from today, if i click on the server i get an Error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:1118080
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.(InetSocketAddress.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.SunAppServer.isRunning(SunAppServer.java:590)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.SunAppServer.isRunning(SunAppServer.java:583)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.actions.AppServerContextAction.acceptIfServerRunning(AppServerContextAction.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.actions.OpenBrowserAction.accept(OpenBrowserAction.java:44)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.actions.AppServerContextAction.selectionChanged(AppServerContextAction.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.SelectionProviderAction.selectionChanged(SelectionProviderAction.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)

So i can't start/stop and deploy my Webapps?

Any ideas???

Thx Tim

Answer (score 2):

The maximum port number is 65535, so check your configuration for which TCP port your server is listening on and set it to a number less than 65535.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. In my case the config/domain.xml of my domain was empty (0 Byte no content). Also deleting the domain with

```
 asadmin delete-domain --domaindir glassfish3/glassfish/domains domain1
```

doesn't worked. So I had delete the domain directory and recreate the domain again (with asadmin).

That's works for me.

Steffen

Comment: Thx - I have reinstalled the glassfish-Server

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and looking at domain.xml I realized that my connection pool description had special characters unescaped. Removing that characters was enough to glassfish to work again